# How to include header files for external libraries in my source code?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, poppler, libarchive

I am trying to extract archived files in my project using Libarchive.
On a standalone code, i include libarchive's archive.h using:

`#include <archive.h>`

But I have seen on projects that header files are not included directly, they use:

`#include <poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h>`

Why is poppler-document.h not directly included?
So how are these directories specified?

Comment: the include<> means the the compiler/linker will look for files in its own registry. that's why you are able to #include<iostream> because it's built into the compiler out of the box. if you include external libraries/packages, you either embed them into the implementation of the compiler you're using (in which case you should be able to use something like #include<package/file>), or you put them into your project folder

Comment: Then why does archive.h is directly included, #include <libarchive/archive.h> gives a error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on visual studio you can go on Project Properties/"C/C++"/General and look at the additional include directories where you can add the directory of where those includes are. For including the .libs themselves you'll need to go in Linker/Additional Library Directories